# Qt: How to determine location / alignment of task bar

Tags: qt, qt4, system-tray, taskbar

what is the best way to determine location of task bar using Qt ?

What I need is the alignment (left,right,top,bottm) and bounderies (left,right,width,height)

Thanks for help in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can infer the orientation of the task bar by comparing the dimensions of the screen against the dimensions of the desktop

```
def get_task_bar_position(self):
    desktop = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget()
    displayRect = desktop.screenGeometry()
    desktopRect = desktop.availableGeometry()
    if desktopRect.height() < displayRect.height():
        if desktopRect.y() > displayRect.y():
            return 'TOP'
        else:
            return 'BOTTOM'
    else:
        if desktopRect.x() > displayRect.x():
            return 'LEFT'
        else:
            return 'RIGHT'
```

Comment: Screen and desktop are different spaces. The desktop space spans across monitors (and even includes invisible areas) while the screen space is confined to the screen (monitor) in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

I think Qt does not provide this facility. You will probably have to resort to the WinAPI to get this information.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: or some linux api to find the Linux taskbar.

Comment: @Power somehow i had to laugh when i read Linux taskbar... Which Taskbar in what Window manager you mean? ;-)

Comment: +1 for sharpness: I meant the top bar in Ubuntu for example. Don't know how it is called there :P (Ah Gnome panel)